# Django 1.11 pass kwarg to modelform field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I would like to pass a kwarg to set a modelform field but im struggling to figure out how to do it.

My URL is as follows:

```
url(r'^tent/create/(?P<munc>\d+)',views.TentCreate.as_view(),name='tent_create'),
```

My view is simply:

```
class TentCreate(CreateView):
    model = Tent
    form_class = TentForm
```

And my form:

```
class TentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tent
        exclude =('asfo','niho')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['primary'].queryset = Mark.objects.filter(munc=self.kwargs['munc'])
```

from the model:

```
class Tent(models.Model):
    primary = models.ForeignKey(Mark,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I can render the form fine without overriding `def __init`, with no filtering applied to the 'primary' field.

However attempting to use the `def __init` code I've described above to pass the `munc` kwarg to the form field is resulting in the following error:
"'TentForm' object has no attribute 'kwargs'"

I've been going around in circles trying to work through this so I would be really appreciative if anyone is able to provide me some guidance to solve this. This is my first Django project so I'm learning how I go so I assume I have made some fundamental error somewhere here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try overriding `get_form_kwargs` method:

**views.py**

```
class TentCreate(CreateView):
    model = Tent
    form_class = TentForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(TentCreate, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'munc': self.kwargs['munc']})
        return kwargs
```

**forms.py**

```
class TentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tent
        exclude =('asfo','niho')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        munc = kwargs.pop('munc')
        super(TentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['primary'].queryset = Mark.objects.filter(munc=munc)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class TentCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = TentForm

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        if form_class is None:
            form_class = self.get_form_class()
        kwargs = self.get_form_kwargs()
        print(kwargs, self.kwargs)
        kwargs.update(self.kwargs)
        return form_class(**kwargs)
```

forms.py

```
class TentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tent
        exclude =('asfo','niho')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        munc=self.kwargs['munc']
        super(TentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['primary'].queryset = Mark.objects.filter(munc=munc)
```

you must pop munc before call `super(TentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Hi Ykh, thank you for your response. I have utilised your code but are still getting the error: "'TentForm' object has no attribute 'kwargs'"

Comment: munc=self.kwargs['munc'] from def __init is where the attribute error is triggering

Comment: have you add method get_form in TentCreate?

Comment: yes using:     def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        if form_class is None:
            form_class = self.get_form_class()
        kwargs = self.get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update(self.kwargs)
        return form_class(**kwargs)

Comment: have you override other method in TentCreate or CreateView?

Comment: I run the same code in django2 and everthing work fine.change `url(r'^tent/create/(?P<munc>\d+)',views.TentCreate.as_view(),name='tent_create')`, to `url(r'^tent/create/(?P<munc>\d+)/$',views.TentCreate.as_view(),name='tent_create')`,

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts to help me here Ykh. I made the URL change but getting the same error message

Comment: It's should work as i expected,try remove model attr in TentCreate

Comment: And add print code in get_form as i did, see what is print.

Comment: it prints as: {'initial': {}, 'prefix': None, 'instance': None} {}

Comment: See self.kwargs is {},this mean you don't pass  arg munc to url ,which url is you asking?

Comment: I assumed I was passing it in: url(r'^tent/create/(?P<munc>\d+)/$',views.TentCreate.as_view(),name='tent_create'),

Comment: the real url you ask in browser is what?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/tent/create/100296/ (where munc = 100296). is this what you mean?